# PyQt5 QLabel errors

Tags: python, pyqt4, pyqt5

In PyQT4 there is a `QLabel()`

While when I use it in PyQT5 it throws an undefined error.

Can anyone one tell me what is Qlabel in the PyQT4 ?

Or maybe I am wrong?

Here is my code:

```
import sys
import time
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *

app = QGuiApplication(sys.argv)
try:
    due = QTime.currentTime()
    message = "Alert!"
    if len(sys.argv) < 2 :
        raise ValueError
    hours, min = sys.argv[1].split(":")
    due = Qtime(int(hours), int(min))
    if not due.isValid():
        raise ValueError
    if len(sys.argv) > 2 :
        message = " ".join(sys.argv[2:])
except ValueError :
    message = "Alert: alert.pyw"

if QTime.currentTime() < due :
    time.sleep(20) #20 Seconds
label = QLabel("<p>Message</p>")
```

Comment: Can you explain more specifically the situation that's causing it to throw an error in PyQT5 but not in PyQT4. ``QLabel()`` is defined in both versions: [PyQT5](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt5/api/qlabel.html) and [PyQT4](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qlabel.html)

Comment: Could you show all code that can be launched?

Answer (score 2):

You should read the [docs](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt5/api/qlabel.html) I posted. Add this import statement with the others:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
```

Answer (score 1):

Because QLabel() is in PyQt5.QtWidgets, please try following :
**from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QLabel**